# Visual Studio Community 2022 inline hints shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut, inline-hints

What is the inline hints on/off shortcut in visual studio 2022?

I checked these checkboxes and it works but the shortcut Alt+F1 not work. (Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.2.0 Preview 2.1)
[image]

Comment: Why is there no option to change this particular shortcut?

Answer (score 4):

I found your question because I was having the same issue. I think I've figured out what's going on.

Are you coding in C# or C/C++ ?

If you're doing C#, HOLDING DOWN the alt-F1 keys will TEMPORARILY show ALL the types of hints available; i.e. those you haven't told it to show all the time. When you release alt-F1 the 'extra' hints will disappear. If, as in your image, you've chosen to show almost everything all the time, holding down alt-F1 probably won't display anything different. (try diabling some of the stuff below the first line and see if there's a difference when you hold down alt-F1)

On my system it reacts rather slowly; if you just tap quickly you might not see any change.

(if that doesn't work, you might want to check to see if any extensions you're using are overriding the alt-F1 shortcut)

If you're using C/C++ the inline hints works a bit differently. Here alt-F1 or ctrl-ctrl can TOGGLE hints.

The options settings for C/C++ are located in "Text Editor/ C/C++ / IntelliSense", and the list of inline hint settings are quite a bit more limited than those listed for C#.

Answer (score 0):

On vanilla Visual Studio 2022 press `ctrl` twice.

If you are using `Visual Assist` press `Alt + F1`

Answer (score 0):

For temporary : **Press and hold** Alt+F1 for some seconds.

For permanently : select the checkboxes you want in TextEditor > C# > Advancded > InlineHints