# Visual Studio lists parameters names in front of arguments to functions in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I recently started using C in Visual Studio, and I've been having an issue where Visual Studio automatically lists the name of parameters in front of arguments to functions. It's possible I unintentionally pressed a key.

Example:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the `_Format:` is being displayed, which is quite annoying. I have browsed through the text editor settings, but I can't seem to find the issue.

I mainly use VS for C#, and so far this only seems to happen with C. Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step, go to options. Press Ctrl+Q then type "inline":

[image]

Second step, uncheck inline hints:

[image]

I use C#, but I think the settings are the same here.

Answer (score 0):

As one answer already stated, this option exists for C#.

But if that doesn't work for C, check the following link:
[similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71913495/12458275)

Quote from the linked answer:

> "If you're using C/C++ the inline hints works a bit differently. Here alt-F1 or Ctrl-Ctrl can TOGGLE hints."

Comment: I first noticed a feature like this in CLion from Jason Turners DOOM stream (recoding in C++), its nice that we now have it, but if you look at the DOOM stream at 06h32 you can see it providing the struct members for each item in an array of structs.

Comment: The VC feature doesn't do this, in our codebase we have some initialisation of a similar array of structs on a longer and more complicated struct so the annotation would be really useful.